Account suddenly cannot perform NTLM logins over VPN
Starting a week ago I cannot login to windows shares or other servers using NTLM authentication over my VPN to our corporate network. Everything else works, SSO etc, Teams, Outlook, just NTLM based authentication fails. The VPN is working as I am logging into other services without windows authentication on our network just fine.
My failure error in the event log of the server:
Subject:
                Security ID:                            NULL SID
                Account Name:                     -
                Account Domain:                  -
                Logon ID:                               0x0

Logon Type:                                          3

Account For Which Logon Failed:
                Security ID:                            NULL SID
                Account Name:                     USERNAME
                Account Domain:                  DOMAIN

Failure Information:
                Failure Reason:                      Unknown user name or bad password.
                Status:                                    0xC000006D
                Sub Status:                            0xC000006A

Process Information:
                Caller Process ID:  0x0
                Caller Process Name:           -

Network Information:
                Workstation Name:              HOSTNAME
                Source Network Address:    MY IP
                Source Port:                          59399

Detailed Authentication Information:
                Logon Process:                     NtLmSsp 
                Authentication Package:     NTLM
                Transited Services:                -
                Package Name (NTLM only):              -
                Key Length:                           0

And a successful login from another user doing the same thing I am attempting:
Subject:
                Security ID:                            NULL SID
                Account Name:                     -
                Account Domain:                  -
                Logon ID:                               0x0

Logon Information:
                Logon Type:                          3
                Restricted Admin Mode:     -
                Virtual Account:                   No
                Elevated Token:                    Yes

Impersonation Level:                           Impersonation

New Logon:
                Security ID:                            DOMAIN\USERNAME
                Account Name:                     USERNAME
                Account Domain:                  DOMAIN
                Logon ID:                               0x4D9A67A9F
                Linked Logon ID:                  0x0
                Network Account Name:     -
                Network Account Domain: -
                Logon GUID:                          {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

Process Information:
                Process ID:                             0x0
                Process Name:                      -

Network Information:
                Workstation Name:              HOSTNAME
                Source Network Address:    THEIR IP
                Source Port:                          56943

Detailed Authentication Information:
                Logon Process:                     NtLmSsp 
                Authentication Package:     NTLM
                Transited Services:                -
                Package Name (NTLM only):              NTLM V2
                Key Length:                           128

If you notice the Security ID is NULL and the Package Name is not supplied. Nothing changed on my laptop, administrators cannot see anything wrong with my account. I changed my password after it started and I can login again to everything else except NTLM authentication. Other users get the Security ID of DOMAIN\USERNAME.

NTLM in 2024? Seriously?

Authentication separate from the VPN works?

Yes it works fine when I'm in my VDI. Everyone elses accounts work fine over the VPN.

I changed my password how did you synchronize that with the notebook?

I locked the machine and entered the new password to unlock it while connected to the VPN.

Can you provide more information on the details of how the connection to the Windows share is made when NTLM is used and fails, and when Kerberos is used and is successful?

The successful login is from a friend doing the exact same thing as me, logging in to Azure TFS, we are both trying the same thing and his succeeds and mine fails. If I remote to his machine mine also succeeds. I may be wrong by saying NTLM just guessing based on the errors.

logging in to Azure TFS sounds like you need to delete/refresh the TFS saved credentials. And remove everything about NTLM and shares.

I did that as soon as the issue started, it's always step #1 to resolving these issues. I removed every credential in credential manager.

HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\LmCompatibilityLevel was incorrectly set to 1. I changed it to 3 and everything works as normal.
